# ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis -- no duplicate axis values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm grouping a data-frame by year (it's one level of a multi-index on the columns ), applying a function that pads out the df to have 11 columns (adding as many empty columns as needed), and then returning the padded df. But this raises an error.

```
finalFormat = (penultimateFormatNot11Columns.groupby( level = 'Year', 
                                                      axis  = 1 )
                                            .apply( padDFToXColumns )
              )




raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")
```

Inside the padding function being applied, the paddedDF that is returned doesn't have any duplicated levels on either axis

```
>>> paddedDF.index.duplicated().any()
False
>>> paddedDF.columns.duplicated().any()
False
>>>
```

Any ideas where this error is coming from?

**Padding Function**

```
def padDFToXColumns( df, TOT_COLUMNS = 11 ):
    """
    Pad out the number of columns in df to TOT_COLUMNS (add TOT_COLUMNS - len(df) empty columns)
    """

    numColsInDF = len(df.columns)
    if numColsInDF > TOT_COLUMNS:
        print("ERROR: Number Of Columns (%s) Exceeds Max Columns (%s)" % (numColsInDF, TOT_COLUMNS))
        return

    ### Add Empty Columns ###
    numColsToAdd = TOT_COLUMNS - numColsInDF
    columnsToAdd = [ 'EmptyColumn' + str(num) for num in range(numColsInDF + 1, TOT_COLUMNS + 1) ]
    emptyColumns = pd.DataFrame( columns = columnsToAdd, index = np.arange(len(df.index)) )

    paddedDF = df.join(emptyColumns)
    #paddedDF.reset_index( drop = True, inplace = True )

    return paddedDF
```

**DataFrame**

```
>>> mydata.head()

     SurveyYear  Age        Race    Gender  WeightAdjusted
0        1996   39     1.White  1.Female         1039.13
1        1996    9     1.White    2.Male          995.13
2        1996    8     1.White    2.Male          775.66
3        1996   39     1.White    2.Male          404.28
4        1996   33  3.Hispanic  1.Female          404.28

>>> groupbyKeys = ['SurveyYear', 'Age', 'Race', 'Gender']
>>> cellPopulations = mydata.groupby(groupbyKeys).agg( {'WeightAdjusted':'sum'})
>>> cellPopulations.head(20)
                                    WeightAdjusted
SurveyYear Age Race       Gender                  
1996       0   1.White    1.Female      1204859.60
                          2.Male        1227666.34
               2.Black    1.Female       307495.16
                          2.Male         263571.07
               3.Hispanic 1.Female       320359.68
                          2.Male         392902.80
               4.Asian    1.Female        78615.49
                          2.Male          82341.54
               5.Other    1.Female        16134.33
                          2.Male          19365.76
           1   1.White    1.Female      1195134.70
                          2.Male        1195659.14
               2.Black    1.Female       328376.10
                          2.Male         383293.79
               3.Hispanic 1.Female       322862.58
                          2.Male         404322.04
               4.Asian    1.Female        79499.56
                          2.Male          73783.69
               5.Other    1.Female        20647.55
                          2.Male          24222.52
>>> unstackKey  = ['SurveyYear', 'Age', 'Gender']



>>> penultimateFormatNot11Columns = cellPopulations.unstack(unstackKey)
>>> penultimateFormatNot11Columns

           WeightAdjusted                                                                                                       ...                                                                                                          
SurveyYear           1996                                                                                                       ...          1997                                                                                            
Age                    0                     1                     2                     3                     4                ...            76                  77                  78                  79                   80           
Gender           1.Female     2.Male   1.Female     2.Male   1.Female     2.Male   1.Female     2.Male   1.Female     2.Male    ...      1.Female    2.Male  1.Female    2.Male  1.Female    2.Male  1.Female    2.Male   1.Female     2.Male
Race                                                                                                                            ...                                                                                                          
1.White        1204859.60 1227666.34 1195134.70 1195659.14 1197386.21 1288700.89 1251324.65 1307458.14 1236790.33 1374989.75    ...     764103.31 506844.04 702775.64 425705.16 666705.33 423419.49 577674.82 366109.58 3898404.40 2283771.11
2.Black         307495.16  263571.07  328376.10  383293.79  291976.23  326400.85  310870.61  323344.13  301025.43  323199.08    ...      68272.99  43254.98  50082.98  34347.45  50788.70  36772.29  31393.21  20720.47  366569.11  180108.23
3.Hispanic      320359.68  392902.80  322862.58  404322.04  344564.20  340702.86  303325.95  321065.53  382663.64  311911.38    ...      39084.04  17362.56  27507.45  18803.48  17619.95  24060.91  35665.78  23802.81  174972.00  105530.84
4.Asian          78615.49   82341.54   79499.56   73783.69   96289.08   88222.32   96411.97   92029.56   77070.10   90370.15    ...      30196.58  27745.90  18419.49  15406.79   7272.27  17891.33  18116.50   3606.67   57684.54   42662.74
5.Other          16134.33   19365.76   20647.55   24222.52   17469.53   27237.94   11220.90    6996.58   23640.43   14917.77    ...       4441.26       nan   1487.90   2845.89    522.43   2453.52    303.66   2982.57   18870.12    6232.88
```

Comment: I think you can add some data sample with error, thanks.

Comment: Added some more information about the underlying data and how it's made.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that all you need is `pivot_table`.

To do that you'll need to `df.reset_index(inplace=True)` after `groupby()` and then:

```
df.pivot_table(values='WeightAdjusted', index='Race', columns=['SurveyYear', 'Age', 'Gender'])
```

Comment: I need to create a data table that has 11 columns for every year. In this case, I have 10 columns for every year (2 genders x 5 Races). I need to add an empty column in every year.

Comment: Is there a way to do that with a pivot table?

Comment: If you want to use that column to perform some aggregation like `mean` you can add `margins=True, aggfunc=np.mean`. `np.mean` is the default one.

Comment: I'm not sure that will work in my case. Maybe I'm not understanding.

Comment: Did you see the "Padding Function" in the original post? That's what I'm trying to do to every year